# Triangulation of Point Configuration

Tags: combinatorics, simplex

I was going through the documentation of Mathematica but couldn't find any built-in function that can find all possible triangulations for a given set of points.

For example, if I have the following points which are the vertices of unit square,

```
points={{0,0}{1,0},{0,1},{1,1}};
```

Then, I want Mathematica to print that there are two triangulations and also give the explicit triangulations.

The above example was straightforward as it involved 2-D points. I'm looking for something in Mathematica which can do the above task for higher-dimensional points as well.

I know this can be done in the software [TOPCOM](http://www.rambau.wm.uni-bayreuth.de/TOPCOM/) using the commands **points2triangs** and **points2ntriangs**, but I wanted to know whether such a thing is implemented in Mathematica as it is done in [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/discrete_geometry/sage/geometry/triangulation/point_configuration.html)

Comment: Look at `DelaunayMesh`

Comment: @DanielHuber That will produce one triangulation. OP wants all triangulations.

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes, I want all possible triangulations. Any idea whether it is possible on Mathematica yet?

Comment: @Epsilon I am not aware of such functionality in Mathematica, but it is quite possible that I missed something that was recently added. You could write an interface to TOPCOM ...